# how to switch item with urlid(path) on item select

Tags: android

```
Hits hits = indexSearcher.search( parser.parse("("+ "text:" +mEdit.getText().toString() + ")"));
String txt2[] =new String[100];
String txt="";
for (int i = 0; i < hits.length(); i++)
{
    Document hitDoc = hits.doc(i);
    Log.i("TestAndroidLuceneActivity", "Lucene: " +hitDoc.get("title")+ hitDoc.get("path"));
    txt=hitDoc.get("title");
    txt2[i]=txt;     
    final String path= hitDoc.get("path");
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Lucenconcept.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,txt2));   
}

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Lucenconcept.this,ShowDetails.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("keyLink", path );
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

I wrote this code for switching another activity but not differing URL-id or path id in bundle. Every url string stored but when I go to next activity.

```
String link = bundle.getString("keyLink");
Toast.makeText(this,link,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Code for retrieving URL-id or path in next activity, but not differ it gives constant url.
Please help me, I am not able to set the position.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < hits.length(); i++)
{
    Document hitDoc = hits.doc(i);
    Log.i("TestAndroidLuceneActivity", "Lucene: " +hitDoc.get("title")+ hitDoc.get("path"));
    txt=hitDoc.get("title");
    txt2[i]=txt;     
    final  String path= hitDoc.get("path");
    ...
}
```

From the above code, it seems that the path contains the last doc's URL; as you are storing the all values in same path variable.
To solve it, you have to get the path value on function `public void onItemClick(...)` and the function contains the third argument as the list item's position on which you have clicked.
write the below code on function `onItemClick(...)`

```
Document hitDoc = hits.doc(<listItemPosition>);
txt=hitDoc.get("title");
path= hitDoc.get("path");
Intent intent = new Intent(Lucenconcept.this,ShowDetails.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("keyLink", path );
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```